# Explanation of this insert into priority Queue Method

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

Will someone please explain this method for inserting into a priority queue for me. I get what occurs when say the list is [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9] and you insert 7. Though I'm failing to see how it properly inserts 10 (or any other number greater than 9). From how I see it in its current implementation if the number is greater than the last number in the queue then it gets inserted improperly. Is this correct? Or am I missing something?

```
 public void insert(double item) // insert item
 {
        int j;
        if(nItems==0) // if no items,
            queArray[nItems++] = item; // insert at 0
        else // if any items
        {
            for(j=nItems-1; j>=0; j--) // start at end,
            {
                if( item > queArray[j] ) // if new item larger, 
                    queArray[j+1] = queArray[j]; // shift upward
                else // if smaller,
                    break; // done shifting
            } // end for
            queArray[j+1] = item; // insert it
            nItems++;
        } // end else (nItems > 0)
    } // end insert()
```

Comment: As far as I see, the method would insert 10 correctly in your example. Imho, the best way to visualize how this works would be to go through the method with a debugger. This will be clearer than any words could describe it.

Comment: what DO you think will happen? state clearly what the question is so we could help you.

Comment: @ImbarM. From what I see it shifts upward until j = 0, then the for loop ends and it inserts at J + 1 (which is 0 + 1). Is this not correct? I suppose I don't understand why there simply isn't a check to see if the element is the largest and to just break and insert right there.

Comment: correct. from the insert function it seems that the bigger the number is the smaller the index (0 index is the biggest number). so what's the problem? i don't see the 'pop' function, but assuming it takes the first item the queue is fine (if the "highest" priority is the biggest number)

Comment: @ImbarM. This solution was said to produce a list in ascending order. (I am sorry for leaving that out). So when I dequeue after this the first value should be the smallest number not the largest. (again according to this solution which was pulled verbatim from a professors lecture notes).

Comment: there you go... then the condition is wrong - needs to be item < queArray[j].

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you're handling the growth of the array. If it's size is 8 and you add to it, accessing it at index 8 will throw an AIOOBE. But OK, assume it's handled somehow.

> I get what occurs when say the list is [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9] and you insert 7

Here is what happens when you insert 7 to [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9]:

```
for(j=nItems-1; j>=0; j--) // start at end,
```

`nItems` is 8 so `j = 7`

```
if( item > queArray[j] )
```

so `7 > 9` is `false`

```
queArray[j+1] = item;
```

if you don't get AIOOBE, the result it [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,7]

So this is already wrong.

> Though I'm failing to see how it properly inserts 10

Here is what happens when you insert 10 to [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9]:

```
for(j=nItems-1; j>=0; j--) // start at end,
```

`nItems` is 8 so `j = 7`

```
if( item > queArray[j] )
```

so `10 > 9` is `true`

```
queArray[j+1] = queArray[j]; // shift upward
```

(AIOOBE) the new array is [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,9].

now `j = 6`, going on with the loop

```
if( item > queArray[j] )
```

so `10 > 8` is `true`

```
queArray[j+1] = queArray[j]; // shift upward
```

the new array is [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,8,9]

continue with the loop you'll get to the end with `j = 0` and `10 > 1` is `true`

```
queArray[j+1] = queArray[j]; // shift upward
```

the new array is [1,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9].

Now `j = -1` fails the loop condition

```
 queArray[j+1] = item;
```

the final array is [10,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9].

So this is also wrong.

Comment: Yes. I made the mistake of trusting a solution that a professor had written. I was posting here to confirm my sanity. You came to the same conclusion I did and after doing what you did in front of the professor he has revised his solution and apologize for insisting I was incorrect. The AIOOBE are handled I was really just looking for confirmation on the insertion being incorrect.

Comment: @bobHarding Good :) Not sure if this is considered a correct answer, but maybe it's good enough to be accepted?